# How many different ways can I arrange this committee?

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

A company has 20 employees, 12 males, and 8 females. Suppose we need to form a committee of 5 employees.

1. How many ways are there to form this committee if we need 3 males and 2 females?
   I believe this is a permutation problem and calculate it as one.
   12 * 11 * 10 * 8 * 7 = 73,920
2. How many ways are there to form this committee if we need at least 4 females?
   Same as the above except we need four females so,
   8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 12 = 20,169
3. How many ways are there to form this committee if we need at least 2 males and at least 2 female?
   12 * 11 * 8 * 7 * 16 (because that's how many people are left) = 118,272.

People got different answers, am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: This seems like a homework problem; if so, it should have the `self-study` tag. See [this help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: It's a practice midterm. Should I still put the self-study tag?

Comment: Yes, you should. If you look at the link, the self-study tag is for "routine questions" - just of this sort. In fact, it was changed from "homework" some time ago, in order to deal with this sort of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True you must use combinations.

1) chossing 3 from 12 AND choosing 2 from 8
\begin{equation}
{12 \choose 3} \times {8 \choose 2} = 220 \times 28
\end{equation}

2) choosing 4 females AND a man, OR, all five are from females
\begin{equation}
{12 \choose 1} \times {8 \choose 4} + {8 \choose 5} = 840 + 56
\end{equation}

3) either we have 3 men and two females, or 2 men and 3 females. 
\begin{equation}
{12 \choose 3} \times {8 \choose 2} + {12 \choose 2} \times {8 \choose 3} = 6160 + 3696
\end{equation}

Comment: Actually I just realized, aren't these all wrong because they should be combinations not permutations?